# How to preserve changes made in AppController.m

Tags: objective-c, unity-game-engine

Unity3d generates a file Appcontroller.mm when it build for Xcode.In this file we can make changes like Adding `CLLocationmanager` callbacks. However if we want to preserve those changes such that when we re-build our project from unity and it generates those files those changes are included on there own. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File / Build Settings (CMD+SHIFT+B) and hit *Build* or *Build And Run*. After selecting an already existing directory Unity3D asks you if you want to replace the existing files or append. Append means that the changes you made are preserved. Hitting CMD+B for building automatically appends. You find more information in the Unity3D manual under [Publishing Builds](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Publishing%20Builds), look for iOS.

Anyway it's a good idea to use a source code control system, because after major version updatesof Unity3D you need to make your changes again.